# Which is faster? Switch statement or dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, big-o

I see a lot of the following enum-to-string conversion in Objective-c/C at work. Stuff like:

```
static NSString *_TranslateMyAnimalToNSString(MyAnimal animal)
{
    switch (animal) {
        case MyAnimalDog:
            return "my_animal_dog";
        case MyAnimalCat:
            return @"my_animal_cat";
        case MyAnimalFish:
            return @"my_animal_fish";
    }
}

NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyAnimal) {
  MyAnimalDog,
  MyAnimalCat,
  MyAnimalFish,
};
```

Wouldn't it be faster and/or smaller to have a static dictionary? Something like:

```
static NSDictionary *animalsAndNames = @{@{MyAnimalCat} : @"my_animal_cat",
                                         @{MyAnimalDog} : @"my_animal_dog",
                                         @{MyAnimalFish} : @"my_animal_fish"};
```

The difference is small, but I'm trying to optimize the binary size and speed, which makes me inclined toward the latter.

Thanks for helping clarify.

Comment: My gut tells me that switch is faster because it’s a language feature and can make more assumptions and be optimized more. Why don’t you try benchmarking it?

Comment: If the enum is 0 based you could consider a C-array

Comment: Space-wise, this is likely to be dominated by the string literals themselves. If you really have a lot of these (so large that it's a serious concern), I would be first tempted to focus on shortening the strings, ideally to 7 characters or fewer so they can be stored as tagged pointers. (Or up to 11 characters if you follow the whacky rules explained here: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) The truth is you'll need to profile. It could go a lot of different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The dictionary should be faster for a large amount of cases. A dictionary is a hashmap, which grants `O(1)` lookup. A switch statement, on the other hand, will have to go through all entries thus requiring `ϴ(n)` time.

### A quick explanation of big O/ϴ/Ω notation

Big-O notation is used to give an asymptotic upper bound to a particular function. That is, f(n) = O(g(n)) means that f(n) does not grow faster than g(n) as n goes to infinity (up to a constant). Similarly, big Ω denotes a lower bound. Therefore, the function f(n)=n+3 is both in Ω(1) and O(n^4), which is not very useful.

Big ϴ, then, denotes a strict bound. If f(n) = O(g(n)) and f(n) = Ω(g(n)) then also f(n) = ϴ(g(n)).

Often using big O suffices, as it makes no sense to advertise a linear algorithm as being in O(n^3), even though it is technically correct. In the case above however the emphasis is on the relative slowness of the switch case, which big O cannot correctly express, hence the usage of ϴ/Ω.

(However, I'm not sure sacrificing readability for correctness was the right choice.)

Comment: For the less mathically-inclined, would you mind giving a short explanation of the difference, please? I'm looking for the O(1) in the question, but I don't know theta.

Comment: @h.and.h edited. Also, in this case you can probably simply read the theta as an O to understand the answer.

Comment: The trouble with big-O here is that it only applies when n is "large" for some unknown value of "large." If n is 3, it's definitely not large, and the constant term (which big-O ignores) can dominate. If I could return you a result in 1 year for any size list (O(1)), or in 1-second-per-item (O(n)), you'd be better to pick the O(n) for any list that didn't have tens of millions of entries. In ObjC, since a switch statement may be heavily optimized by the compiler, it's even less clear. The answer is: profile it.